# Get the last elements in a JSON array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON array like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "A"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "B"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "C"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "D"
    },
    ....
    ....
    {
        "id": "n",
        "name": "X"
    }
]
```

I'm looking for a [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/slice) based function that gives the last 20 item of this JSON array

Answer (score 1):

```
function getLast(array,x){return array.slice(array.length-x)}
```

Just use the slice function starting with the array length minus the number of elements you want to extract.

Comment: Just use a negative argument to slice

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `splice` or `slice`:

```js
// Initialize array
let arr = new Array(50).fill().map((v,i)=>i)

// Pick off last 20 elements
console.log('Last:' + arr.slice(-20))
```

Note: splice modifies the existing array; if you don't want to modify the existing array use `slice`

---

#### Another example

```js
let arr = new Array(50).fill().map((v,i)=>i+1)  // [1,2,..50]

Array.prototype.last = function(n){
  return this.slice(-n)
};

console.log( arr.last(20) )
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way with filters:

```
filteredList = list.filter((_, index) => {
    return index >= list.length - 20
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the last X items in an array I'm not sure you need filter, you can use `.slice` eg `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].slice(-5)` will return `[6,7,8,9,10]`

Comment: Think you mean `slice()`. `splice()` is destructive

Comment: @RoseRobertson youdon't need to correct it, just note it.  In many cases it's better to be destructive than to waste memory.

Comment: @vol7ron fair but I think it's probably smarter to suggest slice here unless I actually were to add a note about the side effects of splice, otherwise it may confuse the person in the future when they go to look at their original array! At any rate, I added an explanation to my edit explaining why the change.